# Execute python script directly, shorcut and execute from startup

Tags: python, tkinter, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I did a application with Python 3 using Tkinter gui, on Raspbian with the RPi. I have three questions:

1) I've turned the python script into executable using:

```
chmod -x path/myfile.py
```

I've declared on the first line of script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

When I double click onthe script it pops up a windows asking if I want to execute normally or on the terminal. If i chose Execute, the script runs normally.

Is there any way to execute normally directly, without asking?

2) How do i create a shortcut on my Desktop to execute my python script?

I've created a file on the desktop and I edited the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Name of the shortcut
Comment=Comment
Icon=path/pic.gif
Exec=python3 path/myfile.py
Terminal=false
```

The picture if the shortcut works, but the script it's not launched. It appears the hourglass and nothing happens.

3) How do I make a python script launch when at the startup of Raspbian?
I've already edited the

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart
```

and also the

```
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

with:

```
@python3 path/myfile.py
```

on the last line of the file. Rebooting the system, nothing happens.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add a thread and inside `while True : time.sleep(1000)`. This thread need will be started `root.mainloop()` **before !**

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. This will also increase your chances on good answers, and will make the Q/A combination more findable and useful to others with the same issue.